# Необходимо показать количество бонусов введя телефон на сайте

Tags: html, формы

Я контент менеджер сайта, попросили попробовать сделать форму в которую вбиваешь телефон, а она выдает кол-во бонусов по номеру. Есть ссылка в формате [https://office.st-pro.su:3443/nikban_http/hs/mobile-app/Balance_html?PhoneNumber=*телефон*](https://office.st-pro.su:3443/nikban_http/hs/mobile-app/Balance_html?PhoneNumber=*%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD*), где *телефон*- это собственно телефон клиента. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при вбивании номера телефона в форму и нажатии на кнопку Submit появлялось кол-во баллов. У меня получилось сделать редирект на данную ссылку, но надо чтобы появлялось на той же странице где и сами формы. Есть возможность сделать это средствами HTML? Прилагаю код. Заранее спасибо!

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="color: #000000;">Узнайте ваше количество баллов по номеру телефона или банному коду.</span></strong></p>
&nbsp;

<form action="https://office.st-pro.su:3443/nikban_http/hs/mobile-app/Balance_html?PhoneNumber=">
<p style="text-align: left;"><input name="PhoneNumber" type="tel" value="" placeholder="Введите ваш телефон" /></p>

    <div id='outerdiv'> 
    <iframe src="https://office.st-pro.su:3443/nikban_http/hs/mobile-app/Balance_html?PhoneNumber="  id="iframe" width="300px" height="50px" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" align="center">
    </iframe> 

    </div> 

</form>
</p>
<button type="submit">Узнать количество баллов</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Так как неизвестно каким методом (get/post) нужно отправлять запрос, и в каком формате должен быть представлен телефонный номер, я не могу протестировать полностью. Но, по идее, разметка должна быть следующей:

```html
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="color: #000000;">Узнайте ваше количество баллов по номеру телефона или банному коду.</span></strong></p>

<form action="https://office.st-pro.su:3443/nikban_http/hs/mobile-app/Balance_html" target="bonus">
  <p style="text-align: left;">
    <input name="PhoneNumber" type="tel" value="+78003022163" placeholder="Введите ваш телефон" />
  </p>
  <button type="submit">Узнать количество баллов</button>
</form>

<p id='outerdiv'>
  <iframe src="_blank" id="bonus" name="bonus" width="300px" height="50px" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" align="center"></iframe>
</p>
```

Comment: Супер, работает, большое спасибо )